# subcolumns not working correctly in tikzposter

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikzposter

I'm trying to arrange content of `tikzposter` using `subcolumns`:

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Ttitle}
\date{01.03.2017}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{todonotes}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\maketitle


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{columns}

    \column{0.5}

    \block{Textbox 1}{
        \blinditemize[5]
    }

    \begin{subcolumns}

        \subcolumn{0.5}

        \block{Fig 1}{

            \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
            \end{tikzfigure}
        }

        \subcolumn{0.5}

        \block{Fig 2}{

            \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
            \end{tikzfigure}
        }

    \end{subcolumns}

    \column{0.5}

    \block{Textbox 2}{
        \blinditemize[10]
    }

\end{columns}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{columns}

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 3}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 4}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 5}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 6}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }


\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that the figures 3 onward are too high and overlay first two figures:

[image]

How can I force figures 3 onwards to appear correctly under the caption of figures 1 & 2?

Comment: where you have defined `\missingfigure`? please, make your example compilable.

Comment: @Zarko I'm sprry but I don't understand the problem.. `\missingfigure` comes from the package `todonotes`and the example above compiles on my machine without any issues..

Comment: sorry, in test I comment this package. I will test again with it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can have `\phantom` `\blocks`. It's a bit of a hack, but if you add

```
\phantom{\block{}{\rule{0pt}{15cm}}}
```

at the end of the second column (after the `\block` with the `\blinditemize[10]`), you'll push the second `columns` environment down accordingly, thereby eliminating the overlap.

[image: output of the code below]

It might not hurt to post a bug report at https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/issues about this, though there hasn't been any activity in the repository for a long time.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Ttitle}
\date{01.03.2017}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{todonotes}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\maketitle


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{columns}

    \column{0.5}

    \block{Textbox 1}{
        \blinditemize[5]
    }

    \begin{subcolumns}

        \subcolumn{0.5}

        \block{Fig 1}{

            \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
            \end{tikzfigure}
        }

        \subcolumn{0.5}

        \block{Fig 2}{

            \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
            \end{tikzfigure}
        }

    \end{subcolumns}

    \column{0.5}

    \block{Textbox 2}{
        \blinditemize[10]
    }

    \phantom{\block{}{\rule{0pt}{15cm}}}

\end{columns}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{columns}

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 3}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 4}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 5}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }

    \column{0.25}
    \block{Fig 6}{
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Fig]
                \centering \missingfigure[figheight=15cm]{}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }


\end{columns}

\end{document}
```